# How to read from org.jboss.netty.channel?

Tags: java, netty

I need to read directly from channel. I'm using netty. in my ChannelHandler, I have this function:

```
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e)

        ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        //I need to read somthing from ch, not from buf
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read directly from the Channel as netty does deliver data read from the channel automatically to your handler. If you want read directly from the Channel you may use directly nio.